# JavaFX: how to set Button size for bigger Font?

Tags: javafx

I would like a Button with a gear symbol to represent settings.  The symbol is too small for the button with the default settings, and if I try to adjust the size of the button to fit, the button loses the text long before it's a reasonable size.  How do I adjust this?  This is what I've tried:

```
package packagename;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ButtonTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        
        Button unchangedSettingsButton = new Button("\u2699");
        Button tooBigSettingsButton = new Button("\u2699");
        Button tooSmallSettingsButton = new Button("\u2699");
        
        double settingsButtonWidth = 40;
        double settingsButtonHeight = 40;
        double settingsButtonFontSize = 36;
        
        tooBigSettingsButton.fontProperty().set(new Font(settingsButtonFontSize));
        tooSmallSettingsButton.fontProperty().set(new Font(settingsButtonFontSize));
        
        tooSmallSettingsButton.setMaxWidth(settingsButtonWidth); tooSmallSettingsButton.setMaxHeight(settingsButtonHeight);
        tooSmallSettingsButton.setMinWidth(settingsButtonWidth); tooSmallSettingsButton.setMinHeight(settingsButtonHeight);
        tooSmallSettingsButton.setPrefWidth(settingsButtonWidth); tooSmallSettingsButton.setPrefHeight(settingsButtonHeight);
        
        VBox root = new VBox(unchangedSettingsButton, tooBigSettingsButton, tooSmallSettingsButton);
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 200, true);
        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Here's the result.  If I do nothing, the gear icon is too small for the button to my liking.  If I increase the font size of the icon, the button grows too much.  If I try to shrink the button, it's too small for the font and the symbol disappears, even though by inspection you can clearly see that it would fit.  I want to force the dimensions.

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything. The button should resize to contain its contents by default. If it's not doing that, post a [mre].

Comment: If I do nothing, it does fit, but the icon is very small relative to the size of the button; the button resizes far more than I would like it to.  Stand by for MWE.

Comment: You can adjust the padding of the `Button` to remove the extra space: `button.setStyle("-fx-padding: -10px 0")`, for example.

Comment: It seems that the glyph is small compared to the actual character (i.e. there is a lot of padding embedded in the symbol). It might be easier to create or get an SVG and use a `Region` with its shape set to the SVG.

Comment: A slight variation of @Zephyr's suggestion is to use `em` as the unit for the padding; something like `button.setStyle("-fx-padding: -0.25em 0em -0.15em 0em;");`. Using `em` means if you change the font size, it should still work without modification.

Comment: Good suggestions all.  I had tried an SVG with other buttons, but it felt like a lot of extra effort to get it to work, if unicode solutions out there are sufficient.  I ended up going with the em units in the padding, and it did exactly what I wanted.  If you make it an answer I'll accept it!  Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, when I run the code I get a similar, but different, glyph.  It definitely looks less like a gear than what you posted.  Maybe going with an ImageView might give more reliable results?